# Insert com select de dois lugares diferentes

Tags: mysql

Meu código ao cadastrar um novo usuário:

```
$sql1        = "INSERT INTO usuario (login, senha_hash, nome, email, direito_deAcesso)
                   VALUES ('{$usuario}', '{$senha_hash}', '{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$direito_deAcesso}')";
$query1      =  mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
```

Depois que um novo usuário é cadastrado, eu tenho que associar ele à um parceiro. Em resumo, um parceiro pode ter um ou mais usuários atrelados e um usuário só pode estar atrelado à um único parceiro.

Assim, depois que o usuário é cadastrado e a query é executada, eu executo outra:

```
$sql2  = "INSERT INTO parceiro_has_usuario (idUsuario, idParceiro)
          SELECT usuario.idusuario FROM usuario
          WHERE login = '{$usuario}'";
```

**idUsuario** e **idParceiro** são duas **foreign key**.

O que eu quero incluir na sql2 pra incluir na tabela **parceiro_has_usuario** (que contém as duas fks) é o nome do parceiro que está na tabela **parceiro**.

Eu tentei algo assim, mas não funcionou:

```
$sql2  = "INSERT INTO parceiro_has_usuario (idUsuario, idParceiro)
          SELECT usuario.idusuario FROM usuario
          WHERE login = '{$usuario}',
          SELECT parceiro.nome FROM parceiro WHERE nome = '{$parceiro}'";
```

Poderiam me ajudar? Aliás, eu não sei se estou fazendo da forma correta para adicionar os valores na tabela que contém as duas fk.

Comment: faz o uso de indices junto com o operador logico AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara no primeiro insert se você usar o returning ele já vai retornar o código do cara inserido.
Ex:

```
insert into tabela(nome, etc) values('fulano', true) returning id;
```

assumindo que sua chave primária chame se id senão returning nome_da_sua_chave

atribua esse id para uma variável e pelo que me parece você já tem o nome do parceiro ai é só jogar os no values do insert mesmo, espero ter sido claro, só uma observação guardar nome como fk não é uma boa prática que ao que parece é isso que você está querendo fazer, não é?

Agora para select nas duas tabelas você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
 INSERT INTO parceiro_has_usuario (idUsuario, idParceiro)
      SELECT usuario.idusuario, parceiro.nome  FROM usuario, parceiro
      WHERE usuario.login = '{$usuario}' and parceiro.nome = '{$parceiro}'";
```

Também assumindo que somente tenho um parceiro com aquele nome, por que senão vai falhar.

Espero ter ajudado.